# Может ли знак за метку исчезнуть?

Tags: поддержка, метки, знаки

Снова наткнулся на [вопрос про возможность знака за тег важное](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311955/is-it-possible-to-get-a-featured-tag-badge). Когда я видел его в прошлый раз, там было больше информации. В том числе, довольно часто повторялось, что знак за метку исчезает, когда рейтинг или количество ответов по этой метке уменьшается. Сейчас это замечание сохранилось только в одном комментарии. Исчез комментарий "даже если получить возможно, то удержать ещё сложнее", исчезли многие другие комментарии (а может и ответы), в которых говорилось подобное.

Собственно вопрос, действительно ли знак исчезнет, когда изменится количество вопросов или ответов по метке? Ведь большинство знаков даются и не отбираются.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Да, может. Знак будет удален,

- если рейтинг по метке станет ниже требуемого (100, 400, 1000)
- если количество заданных и не удаленных вопросов по метке станет меньше чем 100
- или если метка перестанет существовать:

  - удалена (вообще со всех вопросов)
  - переименована (модератором)
  - синонимизирована

В двух последних случаях сразу будет выдан новый знак. Так было на мете, когда переименовали [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) в [обсуждение](/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%81%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5). Тогда Discord, Nicolas Chabanovski и я потеряли старые знаки и получили новые.

Аналогичная ситуация со знаком за 15 рейтинга по 20 из 40 наиболее популярных меток. Если условие перестало выполняться, знак будет удален.

Про рейтинг:

- рейтинг для знака считается только по ответам. То есть задавая только хорошие вопросы по метке знак получить нельзя.
- если метка удалена с вопроса, на котором ваш ответ, то и рейтинг удалится.

Знак выдается только за метки, по которым задано не менее чем 100 вопросов.

Comment: Но ведь в двух последних ситуациях при этом будет получе знак по другой метке?

Comment: Рейтинг по метке - т. е. не только за счёт рейтинга ответов, но и за счёт исчезновения этой метки у вопросов?

Comment: @Qwertiy ответил на уточняющий вопрос.

Comment: @Qwertiy а что, вас беспокоит какая-то конкретная метка и знак?

Comment: Да нет. Мне ещё тогда странным показалось, что знаки могут исчезать, а когда снова увидел тот вопрос, с уже вычищенной информацией об этом, подумал, что может быть она всё-таки была ошибочной :)